# OSM API Way Nodes Ordered Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

So my goal is to be able to pull a given Way from OSM to display on a Leaflet map. However, when I attempt to pull a given Way, the Nodes don't seem to be ordered correctly in the response.

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import xml2js from 'xml2js'

let parser = new xml2js.Parser()

export default {
  async getStpPolygon () {
    let xml = await axios.get('https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/39394541/full')

    return parseNodes(xml)
  },

  async getMplsPolygon () {
    let xml = await axios.get('https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/93481561/full')

    return parseNodes(xml)
  }
}

async function parseNodes (xml) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    parser.parseString(xml.data, (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err)

      let output = data.osm.node.map((node) => {
        return [
          parseFloat(node.$.lat),
          parseFloat(node.$.lon)
        ]
      })

      resolve(output)
    })
  })
}
```

Here is [an example](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/93481561#map=17/44.97372/-93.27504) of the way being displayed on the official OSM map...
[image: Official Map]

and here is the Way being displayed on my Leaflet map.
[image: My Map]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.6.1 (18903 thorn-01.openstreetmap.org)" copyright="OpenStreetMap and contributors" attribution="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" license="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/">
 <node id="1083701880" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6873749" timestamp="2011-01-05T16:51:40Z" user="neuhausr" uid="16591" lat="44.9751170" lon="-93.2758411"/>
 <node id="1083701882" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6873749" timestamp="2011-01-05T16:51:40Z" user="neuhausr" uid="16591" lat="44.9746502" lon="-93.2772842"/>
 <node id="1083701938" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6873749" timestamp="2011-01-05T16:51:41Z" user="neuhausr" uid="16591" lat="44.9727679" lon="-93.2778367"/>
 <node id="1083701987" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6873749" timestamp="2011-01-05T16:51:42Z" user="neuhausr" uid="16591" lat="44.9730222" lon="-93.2787594"/>
 <node id="1083701993" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6873749" timestamp="2011-01-05T16:51:42Z" user="neuhausr" uid="16591" lat="44.9737736" lon="-93.2793709"/>
 <node id="1083702026" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6873749" timestamp="2011-01-05T16:51:43Z" user="neuhausr" uid="16591" lat="44.9754130" lon="-93.2765707"/>
 <way id="93481561" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6873749" timestamp="2011-01-05T16:51:43Z" user="neuhausr" uid="16591">
  <nd ref="1083701993"/>
  <nd ref="1083701987"/>
  <nd ref="1083701938"/>
  <nd ref="1083701880"/>
  <nd ref="1083702026"/>
  <nd ref="1083701882"/>
  <nd ref="1083701993"/>
  <tag k="amenity" v="university"/>
  <tag k="name" v="University of St. Thomas"/>
 </way>
</osm>
```

Note that there are two types of information described in the [OSM XML format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML#Example_OSM_XML_file):

- a list of [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node)

> A node is one of the core elements in the OpenStreetMap data model. It
>   consists of a single point in space defined by its latitude, longitude
>   and node id.

- [a way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) exposing an ordered list of `nd` tags referencing the nodes.

> A way is an ordered list of nodes [...]

So, to get the coordinates in the correct order, you would have to modify your parsing function to something like:

```
async function parseNodes (xml) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parser.parseString(xml.data, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err)

            //map node ids to their coordinates
            const refs = {};
            data.osm.node.forEach((node) => {
                const attrs = node.$;
                refs[attrs.id] = [+attrs.lat, +attrs.lon];
            });

            // return the coordinates in the correct order
            const output = data.osm.way.nd.map((nd) => {
                const id = nd.$.ref;
                return refs[id];
            });

            resolve(output)
        })
    })
}
```

And a demo

```js
async function  getStpPolygon () {
    const resp = await axios.get('https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/93481561/full')

    const json = xml2js(resp.data, {compact: true});
    const refs = {};
    json.osm.node.forEach((node) => {
        const attrs = node._attributes;
        refs[attrs.id] = [+attrs.lat, +attrs.lon];
    });
    
    return json.osm.way.nd.map((nd) => {
        const id = nd._attributes.ref;
        return refs[id];
    });
};


var map = L.map('map').setView([44.97386, -93.27569], 15);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


getStpPolygon().then((points) => {
    L.polyline(points).addTo(map);
});
```

```css
#map { width: 100%; height:200px }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/xml-js@1.6.11/dist/xml-js.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Fiddle available: https://jsfiddle.net/mnf9eL3o/

Comment: Ah, so OSM provides the order within the Way and allows the user to map the Nodes to the references within the Way. Thanks so much for your help, the fix worked perfectly!

Comment: Yes, because multiple ways can share the same nodes. The order of `<node>` items in the file is irrelevant. The order of `<nd>` items matters.